# Why doesn't LOCK TABLES [table] WRITE prevent table reads?

Tags: php, mysql, locking, table-locking

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html if I lock a table for writing in mysql, no-one else should have access until it's unlocked. I wrote this script, loaded either as script.php or script.php?l=1 depending on what you want to do:

```
if ($_GET['l'])
{
    mysqli_query("LOCK TABLES mytable WRITE");
    sleep(10);
    mysqli_query("UNLOCK TABLES");
}
else
{
    $res=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM mytable");
    // Print Result
}
```

If I load script.php?l=1 in one browser window then, while it's sleeping, I should be able to load script.php in another window and it should wait until script.php?l=1 is finished, right?

Thing is, script.php loads right away, even though script.php?l=1 has a write lock. If I try to insert in script.php then it does wait, but why is the SELECT allowed?

**Note:** I am not looking for a discussion on whether to use LOCK TABLES or not. In fact I am probably going to go with a transaction, I am investigating that now, right now I just want to understand why the above doesn't work.

Comment: Could your PHP be set up to use shared mysql connections?

Comment: I will check, but if so, why does the INSERT delay but the SELECT does not?

Comment: I just tried from the `mysql>` command prompt, and locking worked as you expected.

Comment: It looks like it might be related to query caching somehow. I tried in a command prompt too. The first time it worked (the SELECT was delayed), the second time it did not (the SELECT was instant), however as soon as I made a change to the table within the lock session, the SELECT was delayed again. This makes some sort of sense I guess, but it's not what it says it should do. If I WRITE LOCK a table, it should be LOCKED. The current behaviour could break my process.

Comment: In fact, adding SQL_NO_CACHE to the SELECT query makes it work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because of query caching. There is a cache result available that doesn't 'affect' the lock, so the results are returned.

This can be avoided by adding the "SQL_NO_CACHE" keyword to the select:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM mytable
```

Comment: Thanks you. You save my time.

Answer (score 0):

The point of `LOCK` is so that other sessions do not modify the table while you are using it during your specific session.

The reason that you are able to perform the `SELECT` query is because that's still considered part of the same `MySQL` session, even if you open up a new window.

Comment: According to MySQL the WRITE lock prevents all access to the table. Otherwise what's the different between READ and WRITE locks?


As for the same MySQL session, I do not believe this is true, for two reasons. 1: My INSERT was blocked and 2: instead of another browser window, I can do it on another computer/IP and it still happens

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html: "The session that holds the lock can read and write the table."

Comment: For READ locks: "The session that holds the lock can read the table (but not write it)."

Comment: Why do you think they are the same MySQL session (and if they are, how come the INSERT is delayed?)